# Links mysteriously open new browser tab - only for some users

Tags: wordpress, menu, hyperlink, tabs, target

OK, this is a head scratcher.

On a Wordpress site I've made, one particular item of the main menu always opens a new tab when clicked. But only for some users. They claim that it happens on four different Computers (in IE, FF and Safari) as well as on their iPad. I can not recreate the problem at all.

Of course there is no target="_blank" there.

Any pointers as to where to look? I'm at my wits' end.

Comment: by any chance could it have javascript in the menu and these people have javascript disabled if not pasting the code from your menu would be useful

Comment: I've just disabled Javascript in various browsers and still can't recreate the problem.

Comment: Are you in the same physical location as them or could you do a screen share?  Helpful to always watch someone recreate an error.